# Android: Findviewbyid() returns null

Tags: java, android-view

I am trying to make an app with three RelativeLayouts nested in one RelativeLayout. I want to programmatically change the visibility of the RelativeLayouts. It works fine on my smartphone (Android 4.4.2), but not on tablet (Android 5.1.1)

When `findViewById()` is called on the tablet, it returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

MainActivity.java:

```
RelativeLayout mainactivity, multiplewifi, nowifi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) //if switched from landscape to portrait mode or vice versa
        ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webvieew)).restoreState(savedInstanceState); //restore webview
    else {
        Initialize();
        wifiManager.startScan(); //start a scan for available wifi networks
    }
}

public void Initialize() {
    mainactivity = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity);
    multiplewifi = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MultipleWifi);
    nowifi = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.NoWifi);
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/MultipleWifi">

    <Button/>

    <TextView/>

    <Spinner/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainActivity">

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webvieew"/>

    <ImageButton/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/NoWifi">

    <TextView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.wdt, PID: 5243
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wdt/com.example.wdt.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.wdt.MainActivity.Initialize(MainActivity.java:95)
                  at com.example.wdt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: post the stacktrace too

Comment: It can totally can be called on anywhere in your acitivty... That's not your problem...

Comment: You didn't put any id for this line: ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webvieew)).restoreState(savedInstanceState); //restore webview

There's no android:id="@+id/webvieew" in your xml... I think this is the problem

Comment: @Leandro I am sorry I didn't put that in my post, but it is in my xml, I just deleted it in this post because I thought it was irrelevant and that I didn't use the ID of the webview. When I debugged I saw that all three of the layouts (MainActivity, MultipleWifi and NoWifi) `FindViewById()` return null. So not only the variables (mainactivity and so on) are null.

Comment: @Laura, Since you speak about tablet, check if you don't have a `layout` resource folder for large screen, if so, you might find this `activity_main.xml`. It will be the one used for large screen like tablets. If you don't need different layout depending on the screen, simply delete the layout in the specific `layout-large` (for example) folder, it will use the one in the general `layout` folder instead

Comment: @AxelH Thank you! I totally forgot about changing my layout for landscape mode. I will try this, but I am almost certain this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is working on phones but not on tablets, this usually means a problem of resources.

The resources (`layout`, `values`, ...) used by Android depends on the device used. If there is a specific folder that match the device configuration (like large screen), the resource redefine in this folder will be used instead of the general folder.

There is multiple difference between phone/tablet (screen size, ratio, orientation, ...).

In your case, you might need to update or remove the layout `main_activity.xml` in a `layout folder` that match your tablet.

Comment: I thank the internet to have people like you here to say things like this and get other people stuck to solve their coding problems. Does it have someway to edit both files at once or I always need to update individually each file?